# search city in google map do not change the place after searchBox.addListener called for a new place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am working on implementing a new search box to a google map. I followed this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox , and it works fine until it autocomplete places in a list automatically shown suggestions. and it works fine. the problem is that when I click on a city for example, the map does not changed to a new place . I mean nothing exactly happened .

here is my header

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&libraries=places"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and here html

```
<div id="map-container2" class="">
 <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Ville - Recherche">
 <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

and here is my java script functions and I know my problem relates to `searchBox.addListener` , I tried lots of codes , even the one in the link, none of them works.

```
function initialize() {

    centerLocation();
}

function centerLocation() {
    var zoom = 6;
    var position = {
        coords: {
            latitude: 77.040,
            longitude: 2.908
        }
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

    });


    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);




    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });




    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {

        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        console.log(places);
        alert(places);

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }





    });

    markers(position, zoom);
}
```

this line works in console and shows place correctly `console.log(place);`and I have this JavaScript function too for making markers which it works with an array named kine
but I added here may you need to know the structure better

```
function markers(position, zoom) {


    if (typeof zoom === "undefined") {
        zoom = 12;
    }

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if (w < 992) {

        zoom = 5;
    }
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: zoom,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: center,

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    var flag;
    var group = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.kines.length; i++) {
        flag = data.kines[i].group;
        var lat = data.kines[i].lat;
        var lon = data.kines[i].lon;

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

        if(flag > 1) {
            group.push(data.kines[i]);
        } else {
            group.push(data.kines[i]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                icon: "pointer.png"
            });
            var fn = markerClickFunction(group, latLng, map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', fn);
            markers.push(marker);
            group = [];
        }
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code to change the position of the map in the places changed function.  You removed the code in the example that did that.

Comment: my problem is that for example if I type London and choose london from the autocomplete, the map does not chang the view. exactly nothing happened. the  searchBox.addListener called but nothing more happened @MoshFeu could you help me by updating my code?

Comment: You are right. They are blocking users who don't come from the docs. So, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete#try-it-yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed the code that adjusted the map to show the returned results.  If you are only expecting a single result (like a search for "New York, NY, USA"), this will do that:

```
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
  console.log(places);
  if (places.length == 1) {
    var place = places[0];
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      // Only geocodes have viewport.
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    }
  }
});
```

If you are expecting multiple results (like a search for "Starbucks" in New York City), you need to handle the case of more than one result as well.  That is handled in the [google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rgbyo709/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map (after search for "Nebraska")]

**code snippet:**

```js
function centerLocation() {
  var zoom = 6;
  var position = {
    coords: {
      latitude: 77.040,
      longitude: 2.908
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {});
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(places);
    if (places.length == 1) {
      var place = places[0];
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      }
    } else {
      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
function initialize() {
  centerLocation();
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-container2,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&"></script>
<div id="map-container2" class="">
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Ville - Recherche">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```